# DriverManager.getConnection(); How can I determine whether the username/password is wrong or the Driver is not able to connect to the database?

Tags: java, database

Here's my Code:

```
public static Connection connectToDataBase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Driver failure");
    }
    connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.put("user", user);
    connectionProperties.put("password", passwor);
    datenbankverbindung = DriverManager.getConnection(link, connectionProperties);
    return connection;
}
```

I'm connecting to the database, which works fine. But I want to know whether the login data are false or if there's a problem with the connection.

Comment: Oh, why don't you examine the Exception that is thrown?

Comment: I do but I don't know what the Error Message is if f.e. the DriverManager is not able to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

It says that DriverManager.getConnection throws SQLException. So you can catch this exception like:

```
try{
    ...
    datenbankverbindung = DriverManager.getConnection(link,connectionProperties);
}catch(SQLException e){
    ...//do whatever you want
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Verena did it help to understand how to handle your problem??

Comment: I catch it in another method where I already difer if the link or the connectionproperties are wrong. But I also want to know when the link and the properties are correct and theres a problem to connect to the server.

Comment: Until you dont connect to server via getConnection how will you check if username or password is wrong. Do you have correct username and password stored somewhere??

Comment: @Verena if you have one correct username and password with you. Then connect using that. Then check like this select count(*) from mysql.user where user="username you want to check".This will return 1 if username is their. May be this will help.

Comment: @Verena are you not satisfied with the answer?? What problem you are facing now??